# Como obrar ante ediciones mínimas de una pregunta

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuesta, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas

No tengo mucha experiencia en la aprobación de ediciones, y cuando no estoy seguro, las omito.

El caso es que llevo tres o cuatro ediciones omitidas, en las que sólo me encuentro con cambios mínimos, y no se hasta que punto han de ser o no aceptadas.

Por ejemplo, el otro día me encontré una pregunta en la que solo estaban editadas las siglas "css" y cambiadas por "CSS".

Evidentemente, la pregunta se mejora al destacar en mayúscula el nombre de un lenguaje de marcas, pero a la vez, casi veo desmesurada la edición por ese mínimo cambio.

En otras ediciones me he encontrado simplemente con sustituir la letra inicial de cada nuevo párrafo de minúscula a mayúscula, y sí, como indico, la pregunta se mejora, pero me sigo cuestionando si esas mínimas ediciones han de ser aprobadas o rechazadas, pues si se toman en cuenta como posibles todas las ediciones, no creo que hubiera en la comunidad muchas preguntas o respuestas que pudieran salvarse de la edición.

Me imagino que pueda llegar la situación de que por una simple palabra que a alguien le suene mejor que otra, por ejemplo "sustituir" en lugar de "cambiar" puedan llegar a editar preguntas o respuestas a discreción.

Así que si por favor, ¿Me podríais poner un poco de luz al respecto?
¿Son necesarias y permisibles ese tipo de ediciones mínimas?

Gracias.

Comment: nop.. y se rechazan bajo el concepto de que fallan en mejorar la publicación una mayúscula hace un poco mas legible algo, pero que no exista no la hace ilegible...

Comment: Pues muchas gracias por la aclaración @gbianchi, ahora ya lo tendré claro desde ahora en adelante

Comment: Una edición ortográfica, por mínima que sea, mejora la calidad del texto. No veo razón para rechazarlas; el resultado final siempre será mejor que el original y a nadie le producirá daño.

Comment: @CandidMoe si es de usuarios que no tienen todavía permisos de edición, una edición de ese estilo genera ruido en la cola de ediciones y la llena de cosas. Tene en cuenta que por cada edición, uno debería revisar toda la publicación.

Comment: En [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) disponéis de la norma a seguir, en cuanto a ediciones, según el centro de ayuda. Textualmente dice "No os animamos a hacer ediciones minúsculas o triviales: intenta mejorar la publicación considerablemente cuando la edites, corrigiendo todos los problemas que encuentres."